# JWT Authentication Error (401) When Fetching Django API Data from React App via Cookies

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, jwt

I have an API created in Django, which uses a JWT token to validate the user's authentication. Once I log in, I obtain a token that I use to call the 'hello' endpoint to fetch information. Everything works perfectly in this regard, but the problem arises when I integrate it into my React app. My React app allows me to log in and store the JWT token in cookies. In the 'Home.js' file, there's a button responsible for fetching data from the 'hello' endpoint. When I make the request, the Django API responds with a 401, unauthorized error.

If I add token into headers, it works but I don't know if this is the way or I should do in another way:

```
import { useAuthHeader } from 'react-auth-kit'

  const getHelloWord = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/hello/", {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `${authHeader()}`,
        }
      });
      console.log("Response: ", response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR:", error);
    }
  };
```

[image]

***views.py:***

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class HelloView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-gjfyu@1-p1xr_sxj8o5$2l4$qdx81j^vw6=1$^2s)5im68ck4!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'app.apps.AppConfig'
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True  # Permite credenciales (cookies)


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=10),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

My endpoints

```
### Login
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/
Content-Type: application/json

{ "username": "username", "password": "password"}


### Get Hello Word Data
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hello/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; // Importa BrowserRouter
import Login from "./components/login";
import Home from "./components/home";
import { RequireAuth } from "react-auth-kit";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <RequireAuth loginPath="/login">
            <Home />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      ></Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { useSignIn } from "react-auth-kit";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

function Login() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const signIn = useSignIn();

  const onSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    console.log("Values: ", values);
    setError("");

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/token/",
        values
      );
      console.log(response.data)

      signIn({
        token: response.data.access,
        expiresIn: 600,
        tokenType: "Bearer",
        authState: { username: values.username },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err && err instanceof AxiosError)
        setError(err.response?.data.message);
      else if (err && err instanceof Error) setError(err.message);
      console.log("Error: ", err);
    }

    
  };
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      'username': "",
      'password': "",
    },
    onSubmit,
  })

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <Box
        sx={{
          marginTop: 8,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Login
        </Typography>
        <Box component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="username"
            label="username"
            name="username"
            value={formik.values.username}
            onChange={formik.handleChange }
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={formik.values.password}
            onChange={formik.handleChange }
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Home.js**

```
import { Button, Container } from "@mui/material";
import { useSignOut } from "react-auth-kit";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


function Home() {
  const signOut = useSignOut();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const logout = () => {
    signOut();
    navigate("login");
  };


  const getHelloWord = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/hello/", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      console.log("Response: ", response);
    } catch {
      console.log("ERROR")
    }

  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
      <Button onClick={getHelloWord}>HELLO WORD</Button>
      <Button onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: To use cookies, your backend (Django) needs to be configured to read from cookies - have you done that? If not, they usually will only be configured for reading from the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Yes, I did. Check it on settings.py. Maybe I loose some configuration but I did a lot of research and all posts say this config.